# How to choose a cell to be the forecast forward value

Tags: excel

I want to extrapolate a trendline of a graph with the values/periods that a cell consists of. The cell with the value of how many values/periods the trendline should be extrapolated by is regularly being updated so I want to refer to that cell when I choose the values/periods for the forecast forward (under the format trendline).

I have tried to enter the name of the cell (B2) in the box where I fill in the value of the forecast forward but that does not work.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share screen shots of problem? Sample data? Being able to visualize your problem will help to ensure you get the correct answer

Comment: Are you forecasting months? Quarters? Years? What are example values you are putting in `B2`? I imagine a `OFFSET` would be useful but I dont think there is enough info to say for sure